# Rhythmbox with disabled global appmenu

Tags: gnome, rhythmbox, appmenu

I disabled global appmenu and I'm now using GNOME Shell instead of Unity.
My giant love to Rhytmbox fails, because it don't show menu :(
How I can return classic menu? Recompile from sources?

Maybe simple answer exist?

```
$ lsb_release -sir
Ubuntu
13.10

$ gnome-shell --version
GNOME Shell 3.8.4
```

Screenshot (Polish language):
[image: no menu bar in shell]

Rhythmbox version is `2.99.1-0ubuntu1`

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your rhythmbox menu? Can you confirm your ubuntu version? What version of rhythmbox are you using?  Please edit your question with any replies.  Thanks.

Comment: @fossfreedom ok, look now please

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the top of your desktop showing the activities corner - you should have a "rhythmbox" menu next to that.  If you havent, please add a screenshot of your whole rhythmbox application - your menu should be on the right-hand side - probably a "cog" type symbol.

Comment: I writted that I using gnome-shell, on Unity I deleted global appmenu. I don't see any menu like global Rhythmbox menu from older versions.